# swt add widgets towards right in formLayout

Tags: java, swt

Here is my code:

```
Composite outer = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    outer.setBackground(new Color(null, 207, 255, 206)); // Green

    FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    formLayout.marginHeight = 5;
    formLayout.marginWidth = 5;
    formLayout.spacing = 5;
    outer.setLayout(formLayout);
    //TOP
    Composite Top = new Composite(outer, SWT.BORDER);
    Top.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    Top.setBackground(new Color(null, 232, 223, 255)); // Blue

    FormData fData = new FormData();
    fData.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.right = new FormAttachment(100); // Locks on 10% of the view
    fData.bottom = new FormAttachment(20);
    Top.setLayoutData(fData);

    //BOTTOM
    Composite Bottom = new Composite(outer, SWT.BORDER);
    Bottom.setLayout(fillLayout);
    Bottom.setBackground(new Color(null, 255, 235, 223)); // Orange

    fData = new FormData();
    fData.top = new FormAttachment(20);
    fData.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    fData.right = new FormAttachment(100);
    fData.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    Bottom.setLayoutData(fData);
```

I just wanted to add widgets for example label images to the right of the "TOP" composite layout. Since i am new to swt, am facing difficulty to align all the label to right of it. How could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to place another width to the right of `top` you first need to advise `top` to not occupy 100% of the available space, for example only half of the space:

```
FormData formData = new FormData();
formData.right = new FormAttachment( 50 );
```

Or you can leave `formData.right` unspecified (i.e. `null`) so that the widget will use its preferred width.

Once there is room for another widget, you can right-attach one like so:

```
Composite right = new Composite( outer, SWT.BORDER );
right.setBackground( display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_YELLOW ) );
FormData rightFormData = new FormData();
rightFormData.top = new FormAttachment( top, 0, SWT.TOP );
rightFormData.left = new FormAttachment( top );
rightFormData.bottom = new FormAttachment( top, 0, SWT.BOTTOM );
right.setLayoutData( rightFormData );
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

To learn more about FormLayout and other layouts in SWT I recommend the 
[Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) article. Though the article may seem outdated, Layouts in SWT haven't changed since then thus the contents of the article are still valid.

Once you are fluent with the FormLayout and look for a less verbose way to specify the positioning you might want to try [this FormLayout helper](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/03/31/slim-down-swt-formlayout-usage/).